# Pass index variable to the fields_for tag and inside the render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon for dynamic/nested field/forms.

However, I cannot pass the index variable inside the partial file.

Here is what i have in my _form.html.erb:

```
 <% @project_procurement_management_plan.items.each_with_index do |item, index | %>
  <%= f.fields_for :items, item, :child_index => index do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'item_fields', :f => builder, :g=>index %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<div>
  <%=link_to_add_association 'Add Item', f, :items, class:"btn btn-success totheleft" %>
</div>
```

And in my _item_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |c| [c.code, c.id] }, {:prompt=>""},{class:"cat-code #{g}",required:true} %>
```

It says:

**undefined local variable or method `g' for #<#:0x007f82dadeacd8>**

It is pretty clear that the variable `g` as index cannot be read in my partial.

Are there any workarounds to properly pass the index variable to fields_for and into my rendering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over the items yourself! `fields_for` will do that for you.

Remove the loop `<% @project_procurement_management_plan.items.each_with_index do |item, index | %>`.

Do you still need the index now?

Comment: Actually i need fields_for to have an index count. So that i could call the index using my javascript code. That is why i have this `class: "cat-code #{g} " `

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using "locals"

```
<%= render :partial => 'item_fields', :locals => { :g => index, :f => builder } %>
```

Comment: If he uses `:locals`, then he has to use `:partial` too right? `render partial: 'item_fields', locals: {}`. But I don't think this is the source of his problem.

Comment: Actually, the partial isn't still getting the :g variable . But thanks also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved something like this (in haml) by setting a @parameter in mine like so:

questions.html.haml

```
- @answer_index = 0
.answers
  = f.fields_for :answers
  = f.link_to_add "Add an answer", :answers
```

answers.html.haml

```
.answer
  .field
    = f.label :answer, "Answer #{('A'..'Z').to_a[@answer_index]}"
    = f.radio_button :correct , 1, {onclick: "check_answer(this);"}
    = f.text_field :answer
    %span.remove
      = f.link_to_remove "remove"

- @answer_index += 1
```

Not sure if you can pass an @ variable like @answer_index

So for you it might look something like (but not exactly, I'm sure):

_form.html.erb

```
  <%= @item_index = 0 %>
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'item_fields', :f => builder %>
    <%= @item_index += 1 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<div>
  <%=link_to_add_association 'Add Item', f, :items, class:"btn btn-success totheleft" %>
</div>
```

_item_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |c| [c.code, c.id] }, {:prompt=>""},{class:"cat-code #{@item_index}",required:true} %>
```